# How to know before compilation which dependencies a package will need?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I want to install a package on Ubuntu 14.04 using `./configure; make; sudo make install`, however, it is failing due to several missing libraries.

How can I produce a list of needed packages and install all those that are not installed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this :

```
auto-apt run ./configure
```